# Show that number of elements in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is $\varphi(n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Question at the end:
Prove that the number of elements of $(\mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z)^\times$ is $\varphi(n)$ where $\varphi$ denotes the Euler function.
I’ve demonstrated that it works for all n up to 12...
[Work showing n=1-12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nThb.jpg)

It seems kinda obvious that not only does $\varphi(n)$ give the number of elements of $(\mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z)^\times$, but also the list of numbers are the same.

Question: I need a nudge in the right direction here. I can see that it works but I’m not sure how the remainders being equal to the relatively prime factors connects in a proof.

Thanks!

Comment: In my reality, this is the _definition_ of $\phi.$  Do you have a different definition?

Comment: The definition I have for $\varphi(n)$ is the number of elements in a such that a<n and (a,n)=1.

Comment: So the problem comes down to showing that the invertible elements are exactly those which are relatively prime.

Comment: What do you mean by invertible elements?

Comment: The ring $(Z/nZ)^\times$ is the set of invertible elements or "units".

Answer (score 1):

The key to these kinds of things is a clever observation called Bezout's Lemma. It says that if $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers with highest common factor equal to $d$, then you can find integers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$
ax + by = d.
$$
It is proved by applying Euclid's algorithm repeatedly and keeping track of what is happening. The relevance here is that if $m$ is relatively prime to $n$, then you have 
$$
am + bn = 1
$$
for some numbers $a$ and $b$. i.e. given such $m$, you can find $a$ with
$$
am = (\text{multiple of}\ n) + 1...
$$

Comment: OK, so does this reasoning work? Since $\bar{a}\bar{c}=\bar{1}$ Is the requirement for $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^x$... then $\bar{ac}=\bar{1}$ so $ac + kn = ny +1$ ... it follows that $ac + (k-y)n =1$. So we know that a and n are relatively prime and that for every a there is one c with the correct (k-y) chosen to go with the c needed to make $\bar{a} \bar{c}=\bar{1}$. So each a that makes $\bar{a} \bar{c}=\bar{1}$ true matches with one of the a’s from (a,n)=1

Comment: Yeah. OK so I think we were kind of working on opposite ends of the problem. So one strategy to solve this is to take the two sets A =  {invertible elements mod n} and B = {numbers less than n and coprime to n} and show A = B. So to do that we often do two separate aguments: 1. $ A \subset B$ and 2. $B \subset A$. So above I outlined the proof of "If m is coprime to n, then m is invertible mod n". You are essentially discussing "If a is invertible mod n, then a and n are relatively coprime". For your step you need slightly more than the literal statement of Bezout I gave above.

Comment: You need to know that the hcf of x and y really is the smallest number you can make via ax + by where a and b are integers

Answer (score 1):

The criterion for $ax \equiv b \pmod{n}$ is that $(a,n) \mid b$.

If $a$ is invertible then $ax \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ has a solution.  So $(a,n) \mid 1$.  So $(a,n) =1$.  And vice versa.

Comment: OK, that makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

An element $\bar{a}$ (where $a=0, \dotsc, n-1$) is invertible in $\mathbb{Z/n}$ iff $a$ is relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: that seems basically to be the content of the problem

Comment: What do you mean by invertible?